# How to use pure virtual classes

Tags: c++, class, declaration

I have the following very stupid basic question that concerns declarations of classes.

Let's assume that I have a class (name class_a), in my understanding if I want to create a new object from this class I use the following code:

```
class_a* myclass=new class_a();
```

Now I am not sure what happens in this case:

```
class_a* myclass;
```

Is this just a reference that I am using the already created myclass, that was created possibly somewhere else, or does this create as well a new class?

Comment: Learn something on variable declaration, definition and initialization. This might help http://www.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/cpp/cp4_PointerReference.html

Comment: I've edited the title of your question to better reflect what you're asking.

Comment: @KarlNicoll I've reverted your edit because the OP might have been asking about "pure virtual" on purpose.

Comment: @KarlNicoll your new title doesn't reflect what they are asking that well. OP seems to be under the impression that a pointer is needed to create a new object, while it isn't.

Comment: @ChrisW - No problem, but I don't see a single piece of information in the question content that relates it to pure virtual anything. The question entirely discusses basic heap allocation. Perhaps the OP needs to clarify his or her question.

Comment: @KarlNicoll I agree. I guessed that the 'a' in `class_a` might mean "abstract" but that was just a guess.

Answer (score 2):

The

```
class_a* myclass;
```

declares a variable called `myclass`. The variable contains a pointer to `class_a`, but is not initialized (in particular, no objects of class `class_a` are created).

Dereferencing an uninitialized variable would result in [undefined behaviour](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Answer (score 2):

```
class_a* myclass;
```

Is a variable created on the stack. It contains garbage value (an invalid memory address). 
For it to reference (point to) a valid memory location or **"a house that stores `class_a` values"** you can either do this:

```
myclass= new deriv_class_a();
```

Or

`myclass= &some_type_of_class_a;`

To access that house and its values you can do:

`(*myclass).`
`*` is the dereference operator to dereference, and

`"."` is the *period operator* to access its values.
Or to dereference *and* access at same time:

`myclass->someValue`

Comment: But `new class_a()` isn't legal if class_a is "pure virtual".

Comment: @ChrisW You are right, I will fix it. But  I think the confusion here is how to use a class pointer.

Answer (score 1):

Your questions don't seem to have anything to do with "pure virtual classes". That aside,

> In my understanding if I want to create a new object from this class I use the following code

Not necessarily, you can just say

```
class_a myclass;
```

> Now I am not sure what happens in this case: `class_a* myclass;`

You are declaring a pointer to `class_a` called `myclass`. It doesn't point to anything useful and does not instantiate any `class_a` objects anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that class_s is a pure virtual class:

```
class class_a
{
public:
  virtual void foo() = 0;
};
```

... then you can't instantiate it. Instead, you can/must instantiate a non-pure-virtual class which derives from (subclasses or inherits its interface from) this class:

```
class class_b : public class_a
{
public:
  virtual void foo() { printf("hello"); }
};
```

So this is illegal:

```
class_a* myclass = new class_a(); // illegal because class_a is pure virtual
```

This is legal:

```
class_a* myclass = new class_b(); // legal because class_b is not pure virtual
```

The statement above creates an instance of class_b on the heap, using the `new` keyword.

The address of the new instance is assigned to a `class_a*` pointer, which is legal because [class_b is-a class_a](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Is-a).

To create an instance on the stack:

```
class_a myclass_a; // illegal because class_a is pure virtual

class_b myclass_b; // legal because class_b is not pure virtual

class_a* ptr_myclass_a = &myclass_b; // this is legal too
```

The following defines a pointer, but doesn't initialize (assign any defined value to) the pointer, and it doesn't create a class_a instance for the pointer to point to:

```
class_a* myclass;
```

You mustn't use (dereference) an uninitialized pointer until after you initialize it.

Comment: +1 for the detailed explanation. Sad to see the best answer at the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

So in your two scenarios:

```
class_a* myclass = new class_a();
```

In this case, a pointer to `class_a` is created, and then an instance of `class_a` is created on the heap and the pointer set to the address of the newly created instance.

In this case:

```
class_a* myclass;
```

The pointer is defined, but no instance is created. Because of this, `myclass` point's to nothing. You can't use this pointer until you assign it to an instance of `class_a` (or a derived class). Trying to use a pointer than has not been pointed at an instance of `class_a` will result in *undefined behaviour*, which may (or may not) cause your program to crash.

Answer (score 0):

A pure virtual class is a class that is not meant to be used directly but as a base for other classes, but your question body seems to really talk about pointers, so I will try to explain them a bit.

Let us look at `int` first

```
int x = 7;
```

Sets `x` to 7

Now we can set

```
int * y;
```

This will create a pointer to `int` that does not point anywhere so it can't be used yet;

```
y = new int;
```

now `y` can be used as

```
*y =7;
```

when we are done with `y` we need to give back it's memory. Since we did a `new` we need to do a `delete`.   In general, every `new` must be paired with exactly one `delete`

```
delete y;
```

But `y` is still a pointer, but since it's pointing to deleted (unusable) memory we can't use it now. We can use it again if we point it to a different, valid memory address:

```
y=&x;
```

The `&` means get the pointer to, or address of `x` . So now `y` is pointing to the memory owned by `x`.

```
*y = 3;  // note that x == 3 now since the memory is the shared
```

This will also change the value of `x` to 3 since `x` and `*y` are two different ways to access the same memory.  When we are done with `y` don't delete it because `x` owns the memory, and very bad things are likely to occur if you do `delete y`.

In the same way we can apply that to classes:

```
myclass a;

myclass * b=new myclass;

myclass * c=b;

c=&a;

delete b;
```